# jest : how to create separate .babelrc file for jest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, babeljs, enzyme, jestjs

I am new to jest and facing issues with `.babelrc`. As suggested in [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#content), I have to put following content in `.babelrc` file for jest to run:

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

But my project already has .babelrc file with following content:

```
{
  "presets": [
   "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ]
, "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  , "transform-decorators-legacy"
  , "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
  ]
}
```

If I try to run jest with already present file, it gives me error: `ReferenceError: define is not defined`. But if I remove the `"transform-es2015-modules-amd"` plugin property from the .babelrc file, it runs fine. The issue is I cant remove the property as it is being used somewhere else. Can i create separate `.bebelrc` file for jest and map it accordingly or any other solution? Please share if any.

Comment: transform-object-rest-spread is included in stage-0 already...

Comment: just checked, its being caused by "transform-es2015-modules-amd" plugin.. any idea?

Comment: isn´t that plugin pointless anyway? my code gets transpiled correctly without that plugin.

Comment: its an existing app, I am not sure why was that included.. But hesitant to remove fearing code break!

Comment: well, remove it and see what you get ;)

Comment: i have karma tests running as well so cant remove these modules.

Answer (score 0):

For running tests in command line, you can put separate .babelrc file in the project's root dir. For example **.babelrc**:

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

run tests in terminal (console):

```
yarn test
```